# Calculate sum as per record type

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck with the calculation function like the picture, I can only do the summing by debit.

The singer is his system

Saldo = IF THE POSITION Column 1 Column 2 credit debit debit So the result - credit , credit IF Column 1 Column 2 credits , then the result is a credit - credit , credit IF Column 1 Column 2 debit , credit + debit So the result , and so on as the picture

[image: results]

here is my code

```
select 
    no, 
    tanggal, 
    O.debet,
    (select sum(debet) from tbl_jurnal_umum where no <= O.no) 'Saldo'
from tbl_jurnal_umum O 
where nama_perkiraan = 'kas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
/*
DROP TABLE T;
CREATE TABLE T(NAME VARCHAR(3),ID INT, TRTYPE VARCHAR(1), AMOUNT INT);
INSERT INTO  T VALUES
('abc',1,'D','500'),('abc',1,'C','50'),('abc',1,'C','10'),('abc',1,'C','40'),
('abc',1,'D','500'),('abc',1,'C','100');
*/

SELECT S.NAME,S.ID,S.DEBIT,S.CREDIT,s.runtot runningtotal,
         CASE WHEN S.DEBIT <> '' THEN S.RUNTOT ELSE '' END AS  DebitRunningTotal,
         CASE WHEN S.DEBIT  = '' THEN S.RUNTOT ELSE '' END AS  CreditRunningTotal
from
(
SELECT T.NAME,T.ID,
         CASE WHEN T.TRTYPE = 'D' THEN T.AMOUNT ELSE '' END AS DEBIT,
         CASE WHEN T.TRTYPE = 'C' THEN T.AMOUNT ELSE '' END AS CREDIT,
          @RUNTOT:=@RUNTOT + (
            CASE WHEN TRTYPE = 'D' THEN AMOUNT
            ELSE AMOUNT * -1
            END ) 
            AS RUNTOT
FROM   (SELECT @RUNTOT:=0) RT, T T
) s

+------+------+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| NAME | ID   | DEBIT | CREDIT | runningtotal | DebitRunningTotal | CreditRunningTotal |
+------+------+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
| abc  |    1 | 500   |        |          500 | 500               |                    |
| abc  |    1 |       | 50     |          450 |                   | 450                |
| abc  |    1 |       | 10     |          440 |                   | 440                |
| abc  |    1 |       | 40     |          400 |                   | 400                |
| abc  |    1 | 500   |        |          900 | 900               |                    |
| abc  |    1 |       | 100    |          800 |                   | 800                |
+------+------+-------+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```